# Vega mark vs view mouseout events

Tags: vega

I'm trying to write a Vega signal that stores data when you mouseover a particular mark, and then resets when you mouseout from the entire view.

I tried the following:

```
    {
      "name": "mysignal",
      "on": [
        {
          "events": {
            "source": "scope",
            "type": "mouseover",
            "markname": "layer_0_layer_0_marks"
          },
          "update": "datum"
        },
        {"events": {"source": "view", "type": "mouseout"}, "update": "null"}
      ]
    }
```

But when you mouseout of the mark specified the signal gets set back to null, even though I didn't mouseout of the entire view. I have a full spec in the editor link below so you can observe the behaviour I'm talking about. My question is: Is there a way to prevent the signal from being set to null on mouseout from the mark, so that it only gets reset on mouseout from the whole view.

[Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykSArJQBWENgDsQAGhBIGmNhBoAvOGlCYAnjjXoAZnWkgoEzEhriIaEDiQATOxbIgAvjNsOnaAIwA2GRBaADa6xnBBQUZ2SGZoANqg4kgIoTgCAAwABAAyMXDiUJpGxEhBDHBWqAkgmDQpAPo+MgDWAByVNmx29d5GQXkFmvVp6T7pbhp1cI2oAEwt7dY4XT19A4XDGWiz41KTDWgAzAsdy929Mv2Y+RsjR7v702gALCdLKxcgVzdDd6jPDxqUxmAje6DOq0u61+W1QGQmQIOqH8IDapw+a2ug02o2RgNqSIA7GDOudMT8cWhCfjgWhWiSIZ9vti-q0aUiAJwMjFQrG3WFshEEp6obzpblk3kUv5i9ki7wS+qzcks2FioW0uaK5VS1W42YCDVI46oxbglY6r7QylwuUzV6m9HdS3M-m4gFGkWgx3vZ0qt1oeF7REilFo31K-0w3G+O1U7VRm3UlwAXQRSRS1miZnqowCbAYACcoKkMjloUZMIWkJY9GxCwh4hptKE6w2GP0jHAAB44QvWBQAETyAApswwEHEADoh+ozlMASiMSA6wsaqdTARoZCSQUq1QzoQA7jQ7PQjBZDOgaBAAGKX64jkziMwWOCFgDKKjgI4XcXSi6ZAA-Jkz6vuI75fqov7-immSoJkOx5iAEhNiADA4NmoQ3ve4h0D+YHmBBn7fjBAELsBoGmERkGkX+AHwYh6TIXApAvh0J7iHYbBHqghYVN+rhpsGh7WPA25YBeeGYNYOEPgR1FviR0F-t4gEgYRSlQT+qlwQhSFGKhVSgBhWGyXe8lPopxHaTBakURp1m0SpcRqYxBkyKx+SYBxFjcbx-FKKoQnpskoQIJoSg7qUhmSMZIBeex6ggGIRYltY0BsDolYttYCAFhAcBsKQ-YyMghbNKJ6D9Jo765vUNV1ek9Tlc0VhuOhmF5FmMQTq4waJT5yWpcWoTEDQcBHjl2XoPlDCFQWMkdaZ3XoOIHaRBuKZlUgFX7okYXWI1hb1cd9W2PQZCFgWODTaEV03UYejXY2qCgHoSAljJb0gFVIAfV9cDdBdMANUgtUnc1Z3NcgFhRDEKDoNmSC5kYD0YUwRRVD6aYdTcXS6CZXXXMlJ5njAyUGOEdjJejt3oGT54uB14lkJJP1U0ENM-XTYlwBJS3Mx1rX7b9h3VeDTVgxD9Ui3dR1vkYgSaCE8RfIr20pfW33vRNXM9ZgE7TrO879f9L3Jcj1gA3A1zAzEoPQ9LUuw5IeMFATyUrSTP2BNdzSEylUClKEJhBPWT169zPodd2w3B6r6BxzInPR2uZtY6A0Ah9YRQp1HR3WncHV+2wAcAOqnueP0lGUuiGjIWWfXQmcgLX5Q+ELW0BAnFRoX9yc1Ll6DClEbCu5bCMGyjyGpwOtIddW4hkLo-7BlFu7WIzFMbiJ4sgHnQ8zerEG7WPE8-VbSMI6j+fU4XfLRmbS8r2hG8xegrOSW4AEyKo11oA+nuOAMg8LpVQFWcooVMzoDDhHGQWhj71kcJvGQ3EL6gCviAZGt9-oF3QOGfMhZvqQLgIvGsr9YF5DIPWIo0DQj1G7PUd+kQEHDxDOfIik9YjXxzLPfBs5n4UNXuKLO25N4MyrjvNMmskDdj7vFbOicD6GULBNF8R04B6BkjIK6p4Py92sIPPR3NSEIJoFAZoABhAsGjfbiI-mEGgQQRxf0wAQAES4OroK4agIBhUoRMHCJUfxICQDIG7AAUW7Fib64pwkWGibEtA8TaiWJCaUAJIBlB+R7CkhESjQiD3rOo76IAmBsGwOPNGajuahMCeEW8ZQIAUwgYWco5jLE2IYHYsR0VIiwP5i47eBAdheIaUEAA8iVfo9MzHZNyXHVAgJCm51UaUzR2iamnkAZksJtRMDKIAApllyI-TII4EAQCXBM6Z75ZloHmWk6xtidYpQcQMpxLi3EePSOMhZXE8nLI3EAA)